# apt-get can't install (dependency conflicts?)

Tags: dependency-management, apt

I'm having a problem with `apt-get`.  I'm trying to install `gsoap`, typing

```
apt-get install gsoap
```

but I'm getting

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Breaks: gcc-4.4 (< 4.4.6-4) but 4.4.5-8 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

**Question 1: can someone translate this into English?**

I tried running `apt-get -f install`, but all it said was "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1153 not upgraded".

This is really frustrating.  I know dependency management is a hard problem, but I thought it was the job of a tool like `apt-get` to solve that problem for me.  In this case it feels like there's something it's decided it can't do, and it's expecting me to resolve it, but it's telling me what's wrong using language which I frankly do not understand.

Question 2: is there something I could read to help me understand apt's dependency management philosophy, so I could maybe understand what's going on here?

If I should be asking these questions somewhere else let me know.

---

Addendum: per the Debian bug report linked to by mertyildiran, there was definitely a dependency problem involving gcc-4.4 and squeeze (which is in fact what I'm running).  That bug claims to be fixed, but somehow the fix isn't helping me.

I suspect it may be time to ask **Question 3: Is there a way to hand-edit the dependency list to make this problem go away?**  That's a terrible idea, I know, but at this point that may be my only choice other than blowing away the whole machine and reinstalling squeeze or wheezy from scratch, and that's a daunting prospect.

Comment: I have completed my answer, please take a look.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command

```
sudo apt install aptitude && sudo aptitude install gsoap
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be that @JosephWorks' solution

> ```
> sudo apt install aptitude && sudo aptitude install gsoap
> ```

actually helps with

> Question 3: Is there a way to hand-edit the dependency list to make this problem go away?

Aptitude offers several configuration/downgrading options that installs the package you wish for. You can list the different options with `n` and choose one with `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

@Steve You wanna try this ?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: No, I don't wanna try that, I want to understand what's going on here.  (Trying things without undertanding them is, I think, how I got into a state where `apt-get` is confused and can't fix things.)

Comment: Okay, having read the Debian bug report that mertyildiran linked to, it looks like installing build-essential(s) is supposed to be a solution to some version of my problem, but it din't help me; I'm getting "build-essential is already the newest version".

Comment: @SteveSummit i have this code to fix broken packages `sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update`

Comment: What does `dpkg --configure -a` do?  Anyway it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This solution has been reported in several forums:

```
sudo apt-get clean && apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install gsoap
```

Sources:

- http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=70540
- http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/debian-linux/182874-apt-get-install-complains-broken-packages.html

Debian Bug report about the issue: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=676483

**Explanation:**

Let's see the functionality of `clean` argument with `man apt-get`:

```
   clean
       clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. It removes everything but the lock file from
       /var/cache/apt/archives/ and /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.
```

Simply `clean` will reset your local package index so you can `update` your package index in most clean way.

I believe you have made a `dist-upgrade` in the past or **manually** edited your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Maybe a **PPA(Personal Package Archive)** that you have used caused this problem.

If the error persists:

**Compile and Install gcc-4.4.5**

Download gcc-4.4.5: http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.4.5/gcc-4.4.5.tar.gz

```
tar -zxvf gcc-4.4.5.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.4.5/
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo apt-get install gsoap
```

Probably you have an old distro. Ubuntu 16.04 comes with gcc-5.4.0. Installing gcc-4.4.5 should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, those links are helpful.  (For the record, though, the apt-get clean / update / install -f recipe did not help at all; I'm still getting exactly the same message trying to install gsoap.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Could you add the output of `gcc --version` to you question.

Comment: apt clean does nothing with the local package index, and will not help with dependency problems. all it does is delete downloaded .deb files from the cache.